# Correct way to add Items to Verticle List?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to create PreviewList in `VerticleScrollBar`. The preview item will have an `TRectangle` an `TImage` and an `TLabel`.

My Form contains three buttons `btnLoad` `btnAdd` and `btnClear`.

on `btnLoad` Click i am loading picture in Image1:

```
procedure TForm3.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
   Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
end;
```

on `btnAdd` Click i am adding the PreviewItem to `VertScroll` and adding string to the `StringList` which will be used to print images (not implemented yet):

```
procedure TForm3.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
mRect: TRectangle;
mbit: TBitmap;
mImage: TImage;
mTitle: TLabel;
mDeleteBtn: TButton;
begin
  SL:= TStringList.Create;

  mRect:= TRectangle.Create(VertScroll);
  mRect.Height:= 60 ;
  mRect.Align:= TAlignLayout.Top;
  mRect.Margins.Bottom:= 2;
  mRect.Position.Y:= I * mRect.Height;
  mRect.Parent:=VertScroll;

  mBit:= TBitmap.Create;
  mBit.Height:= Image1.Bitmap.Height;
  mBit.Width:= Image1.Bitmap.Width;
  mBit.CopyFromBitmap(Image1.Bitmap);

  mImage:= TImage.Create(mRect);
  mImage.Parent:= mRect;
  mImage.Align:= TAlignLayout.Top;
  mImage.Height:= 50;
  mImage.Bitmap.Assign(mBit);
  mImage.WrapMode:= TImageWrapMode.Tile;
  mImage.OnClick:= mImageClick;

  mTitle:= Tlabel.Create(mRect);
  mTitle.Parent:= mRect;
  mTitle.Align:= TAlignLayout.Bottom;
  mTitle.Text:= 'Image'+ IntToStr(i);
  mTitle.Height:=10;

  mDeleteBtn:= TButton.Create(mImage);
  mDeleteBtn.Parent:= mImage;
  mDeleteBtn.Width:= 20;
  mDeleteBtn.Height:=20;
  mDeleteBtn.Text:= 'X';
  mDeleteBtn.OnClick:= btnDeleteClick;

  I:= I + 1;
  SL.Add(mTitle.Text);
  ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(SL);
  Sl.Free;
end;
```

on `btnClear` i am clearing everything to fresh:

```
procedure TForm3.btnClearClick(Sender: TObject);
var
j: integer;
begin
  SL:= TStringList.Create;
  Sl.Clear;
  SL.Free;
  for j := VertScroll.ComponentCount - 1  downto 0 do
begin
  if (VertScroll.Components[j] is TRectangle) then
  begin
    (VertScroll.Components[j] as TRectangle).Free;
  end;
end;
  ListBox1.Clear;
  I:= 0;
end;
```

on `mDeleteButton` Click i am trying to delete the component from scrollbar and removing string from StringList:

```
procedure TForm3.btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
j: integer;
begin
  VertScroll.BeginUpdate;
  SL:=TStringList.Create;
  j:= TButton(Sender).Parent.Parent.Index;
  sl.Delete(j);
  ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(SL);
  TButton(Sender).Parent.Parent.Destroy;
  VertScroll.EndUpdate;
end;
```

**Update**

The Creation of Preview Item is all Working but when i try to remove on the items from the ScrollBar using btnDelete it raises `Index Out of bound` error on `Sl.Delete(j)`

why it is not removing the `StringList` string from that index ?

How i can handle this operation correctly ?

**Update 1**

How can i access `TImage` from `TRectangle` in PreviewItems of `VertScroll`
this is current code i am trying :

```
    for k := 0 to TRectangle(VertScroll.Components[j]).ChildrenCount - 1 do
        begin
          if TRectangle(VertScroll.Components[j]).Children[k] is TImage then
          begin
            img.Bitmap.Assign(TImage(TRectangle(VertScroll.Components[j]).Children[k]).Bitmap);
          end;
        end;
```

Comment: why do you create a TStringList and Free it immediate after use ? Seems like you dont need a TStringList at all

Comment: @GuidoG Hii That's human error. but will be using the string list to print images that are in previewitems of vertscroll as i said the printing part is not implimented yet. I've updating my question please take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TForm3.btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
j: integer;
begin
  VertScroll.BeginUpdate;
  SL:=TStringList.Create; // You create an empty stringlist here i.e Count = 0
  j:= TButton(Sender).Parent.Parent.Index;
  sl.Delete(j); // You are telling your code to delete from an empty stringlist
  ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(SL);
  TButton(Sender).Parent.Parent.Destroy;
  VertScroll.EndUpdate;
end;
```

The reason you are having the out of bound error is because the StringList is empty. You are using a global variable for the list but you keep assigning a new instance to it each time.

Consider creating the string list once in your MainForms constructor and Free it in the destructor of your form.

Finally a simple debugging would have let you see this. consider going this way now and on.

Comment: whoops ! just realized that. just one more thing can please tell me how can i access `TImages` from `TRectangle` in `VertScroll` i mean Accessing the Timages from previewitems in VertScroll bar so i can use those bitmaps i've updated the question please take a look at it.

Comment: @John I think you will have to use find component by using the Children property of main form or VertScroll if it has one. See [this](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/firemonkey-findcomponent-functi/1043271). and At last please stop editing the question and changing its context. Consider asking a new one. people will be happy to answer all your questions as long they follow the [ask] rules.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout Why you're calling `Destroy` instead of `Free`

Comment: @Sami because it is not my code. I did not write that code, The OP did. I copied it as a quote.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Owner of mRect should be the VertScroll, not Form3, so please change to this:

```
mRect:= TRectangle.Create(VertScroll);
```

In btnClearClick remove **j** variable and simply use **0** in places where you have **j** now.

Also, you are using TStringList without any reason, you are creating it just to destroy/free it. Remove the SL variable, just use ListBox1.Items (or explain why you want SL to be a copy of ListBox1.Items)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but it didn't helped me much. For `StringList` as i said the printing part is yet to be implimented so for now i am using string list to updated the listbox only to see whether it is working or not. Please see the updated question.